# SQL DB2 - problem with combining rows from 2 tables into one output

Tags: sql, join, db2, output, union

I am having issues combining rows from 2 tables, and I can't figure out how to get UNION to work.
I have 2 database tables:

- TFBCR
- TFBCAI

TFBCR table contains these columns:

- FBC_REQ_REF_NBR (primary key)
- CLT_ID_A
- FBC_STATUS_CD

TFBCAI contains none, 1 or many rows depending if the above FBC_STATUS_CD is anything but '00'. It has:

- FBC_REQ_REF_NBR (foreign primary key)
- CLT_ID_B
- BALANCE

I am trying to show all rows from both tables, even when FBC_STATUS_CD is '00' or anything else.

Right now it is only outputting rows that have the STATUS_CODE anything but 00 because of how I am linking the 2 tables. How can I have something like this:

```
FBC_REQ_REF_NBR     CLT_ID_A      FBC_STATUS_CD  CLT_ID_B    BALANCE
1                   JOHN          00             --------    --------
2                   ADAM          11             ADAM_1      25.00
2                   ADAM          11             ADAM_2      10.00
2                   ADAM          12             ADAM_3      50.00
3                   SAM           00             -------     --------
4                   DAVE          13             DAVE_1      65.50
4                   DAVE          12             DAVE_2      55.00
```

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT
  A.FBC_REQ_REF_NBR,
  A.CLT_ID_A,
  A.FBC_STATUS_CD,
  B.CLT_ID_B,
  B.BALANCE
FROM TFBCR A,
     TFBCAI B
WHERE A.FBC_REQ_REF_NBR = B.FBC_REQ_REF_NBR
ORDER BY A.FBC_REQ_REF_NBR
WITH UR;
```

I need the single rows from TFBCR that have a 00 status code AND all the rows from TFBCAI (if they exist). I am guessing this is done with some kind of subselect, but I can't figure it out.

Thank you!!

Comment: What is `with ur`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with UNION. Why don't you try RIGHT or LEFT JOIN on key fields instead of the WHERE linking?

Comment: Are the records 1:1 at most or is it possible there's > 1 TFBCAI record for a single TFBCR record?

Comment: @GordonLinoff. `with ur` is for reading uncommitted records. Yay, dirty reads!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a `LEFT JOIN` of `TFBCR`  to `TFBCAI`:

```
SELECT
  A.FBC_REQ_REF_NBR,
  A.CLT_ID_A,
  A.FBC_STATUS_CD,
  B.CLT_ID_B,
  B.BALANCE
FROM TFBCR A LEFT JOIN TFBCAI B
ON A.FBC_REQ_REF_NBR = B.FBC_REQ_REF_NBR
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN... genius. Thank you so much, it was so simple! I've been staring at this for hours and knew it had to be something so easy. Thank you friend!